# Specify run-time and build-time dependency in CMAKE

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, ldd

I am using CMAKE to build shared library `camera`, which is depending on `api.so`, which is also shared library. Library `camera.so` is used by `server` executable, I am on linux.

I have CMAKE build directory in `~/projects/server/camera/build`.

Server in production environment has following strucuture:

- `/opt/server`

  - `server`
  - `api.so`
  - `/lib/`

    - `camera.so`

I have following CMAKE script:

```
SET(LIB_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Release)
ADD_LIBRARY(api SHARED IMPORTED)
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET api PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIB_DIR}/api.so)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(camera
        api
)
```

Variable `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` contains `~/projects/server`.

I need to use `IMPORTED_LOCATION`, because `api.so` library name doesn't start with `lib`, there is nothing else I can do about it, it's working.

I successfully build `camera.so`, then I place it on production server to  `/opt/server/lib` directory. When I run `ldd /opt/server/lib/camera.so`, I can see that libary is looking for `api.so` in directory where I have it on build machine, but I would like to force library to look for it in run time one level up, so in `../api.so`.

I don't care if it will be by using relative path or by absolute path, but **it needs to be somewhere else than in place where I use it for linking on my computer**. I don't wan't to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, solution should be done in CMAKE script.

I found so far and tried:

`SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/../")`

`SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../")`

But `ldd` still keeps telling me that it's looking to my build dir, which doesn't exist in production.

Can you please tell me what CMAKE command should I use to solve this problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` affects on RPATH for **installed** libraries (with `install()` command).

For propagate these settings for built libraries, set [CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH.html) variable:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH ON)

add_library(...)
```

Comment: I see, that could be the reason. I am out of office, I will be back on monday, then I try it. If it works, I will mark answer as accepted. The only problem I can now think of is that we run on ubuntu 14.04, where is older CMAKE version, it will be older than 2.xx. Do you know in what CMAKE version was CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH introduced?

Comment: You may always visit [CMake documentation page](https://cmake.org/documentation/) and look into the documentation for the specific CMake version.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I added two lines you suggest, then tried with both 2.8.12.2 (ubuntu 14) and also 3.5.1 (ubuntu 16) CMAKE version. I removed all the content of `build` directory, run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo ..`, then `make -j4`. When I run `ldd camera.so` on created binary, I can see that it's still looking for `api.so` in my build directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had to find some solution by myself, because it's quite a while since I posted the question. Maybe it's workaround, I don't know, I didn't find better solution, it works.

**Solution proposed by Tsyvarev works for libraries built within the same Cmake project**, but doesn't work for libraries built by someone else, which is my case.

I decided to create **symlink in /usr/lib** to the directory with shared libraries I need to link with my library. So there is the same symlink on server and on my build machine, but pointing to different place with libraries.